# MS SQL Server Management Studio - Compare Database Values

Tags: sql-server, database, compare

Im new in an IT Concern, where im the only programmer.

My new task includes understanding a Database used by program that is not owned by us. My Task is to import Data into this Database, so the program using it can use the data.

The Program itself has this function where users can enter a single entry. But since there are like thousands entries i have to put into the database ill have to write a program for that (that pretty much doing the same... just automatically). I can't look into the source code of the program.

So what i need is to find out what exactly is written into which table of the database, when i add an entry. Looking it up manually is no option because the database contains more than 60 Tables.

So i need to find a way to compare all values of the Database BEFORE i did one new entry and AFTER i did the entry. I want to only see the changed tables, where values have changed. Is there a free tool out there which does the job for me, or do i have to create it on my own?

I'm sorry for my English :P
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try making an isolated copy of the program, empty the database and do 1 insert. Then check what tables have 1 record.

Comment: You could run Sql Profiler to trace what happens when you add an entry

Comment: @ar34z Good idea, but no way this is working. For example there is one Table where all dates are put in: UserDates for meetings as well as dates for holidays. So selecting where count = 1 wont give me 100% correct informations.

Comment: @EricZ thats a pretty sweet tool, i cant deny that. By filtering where TextData "Like %select%, %insert%" i found alot more information. Sadly the hard part of the job just seems to be beginning; Understanding what exactly the entrys mean and how they are done (for example: 42356 is the value  in an int Field called "date")